# Can we fit cordova InAppBrowser to a section of HTML, instead of covering the whole screen?

Tags: cordova, iframe, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

Currently InAppBrowser covering the whole screen after launched. Is it possible to we fit cordova InAppBrowser to a section of HTML, instead of covering the whole screen?

If not is there any other option for this need?

Side note - Already explored iframe and I don't want to go with that due to security reasons.

Kindly give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

From plugin source code (for example Android, see: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/src/android/InAppBrowser.java),

```
inAppWebView = new WebView(cordova.getActivity());
inAppWebView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

The `WebView` uses style: `MATCH_PARENT` and its appended to `main` view a.e. root. For that reason you we always get full screen

So you can try to play with plugin code and see what will happen

Comment: Is there any configuration thats available to pass to plugin? Or Fix height outside plugin from our code.

Comment: @EaswaramoorthyK I don't think so. you can manage it by yourself

Comment: @Bloodhound No, I am living with full screen as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Could this help you?

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Look under Firefox OS Quirks.